# The dimension of the tangent space of a point in affine algebraic variety and in its irreducible component

Tags: tangent-spaces, affine-varieties

Let V be an affine algebraic variety, and P be a point in V. V' is an irreducible component of V that contains P.

I want to prove the tangent space of P in V and the tangent space of P in V' have the same dimension, what i know is that dim$(T_{P}(V'))$ is smaller than dim$(T_{P}(V))$. But i don't know how to prove they are equal.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: They are both 2, aren't they?

Comment: Oh, sorry, they aren.t both 2. One is 2 and another is 1. Thanks. And I want to add one question: if P is contained in only one irreducible component V', then in this case, we have the equality?